Can we reverse the elements in a Singly Circular Linked List using only two pointers? Is that possible, efficient and what is the time complexity?
I need to know about only one thing clearly, as I had tried the singly circular linked list reversal using the C language. In that I can't find the correct way and I have no idea regarding this one. Can someone help me to get in a correct way and brief about the time complexity and finally can't we reverse without declaring to NULL?
struct node *Reversescll(struct node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head->next = head;
        return head;
    }

    struct node *back = NULL;
    struct node *c = head;
    struct node *next = NULL;

    do {
        next = c->next;
        c->next = back;
        back = c;
        c = next;
    } while (c != head);

    head->next = back;
    head = back;
    return head;
}


Did you mean to put something in the spoiler section?

Yes, yes, somewhat (b/c linked lists are inherently inefficient), O(n).

if (head==NULL) { head->next==head; won't end well.

You're missing ; after while(c!=head)

See https://medium.com/@acharya.piyush224/reverse-a-link-list-using-recursion-81a90fef850c for a recursive list reverse algorithm.  it only uses one pointer per iteration.

Please learn how to format your code properly. This is very important. Unreadable code is hard to work with, especially for beginners. I've done it for you.

Is the "using only two Pointers" part of the headline actually relevant?  I was going to ask about how you count, but then I saw that the code in the question uses more than two any way you count.

Your approach is almost correct, but you have a problem with the empty list: you should just return head or NULL and not dereference head->next when head is NULL.
Here is a corrected version:
struct node *Reversescll(struct node *head) {
    if (head == NULL || head->next == head)
        return head;

    struct node *back = NULL;
    struct node *c = head;

    do {
        struct node *next = c->next;
        c->next = back;
        back = c;
        c = next;
    } while (c != head);

    head->next = back;
    return head;
}

Note that the function always returns its argument.
Now to fully address your question:

Can we reverse the elements in a Singly Circular Linked List using only two pointers?

Yes, it is possible to do it with just 2 extra pointers in addition to the head argument (the above code uses 3 extra pointers):
struct node *Reversescll(struct node *head) {
    if (head == NULL)
        return head;

    struct node *back = NULL;
    while (head->next) {
        struct node *next = head->next;
        head->next = back;
        back = head;
        head = next;
    }
    head->next = back;
    return head;
}


Is that efficient and what is the time complexity?

It is efficient and the complexity is linear, O(n). This is optimal as every node must be changed.

The OP's word order is odd, but I think they're saying that they have a circular (singly-)linked list.  If so, then your while (head->next) loop will not terminate.

@JohnBollinger: I beg to differ, since the initial node's next pointer will be set to the initial value of back, namely a null pointer, the loop will stop when it reaches this node again if the list is indeed circular.  If the list is not circular, the classic code in the first version here above will crash when reaching the null pointer whereas this code will stop at the last node, link it the the previous one and return it.  IOW the code reverses the list whether it is circular or not.  The initial test head->next == head is not even needed.

My apologies.  I seem to have just popped over from the alternate universe where you didn't do that.  I know this because I looked for something along those lines before commenting.  +1, then.  Never mind me.
